# Openlayers SelectControl add multiple Layers

Tags: openlayers-2, select, markers

Heres my code to add an SelectControl with Popup for an existing layer add startup

```
    map.addLayer(window.markerLayer);

window.markerLayer.events.on({

});

// Popup für Marker
window.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([markerLayer]);
map.addControl(window.selectControl);

window.selectControl.activate();
    window.markerLayer.events.on({
    'featureselected' : onFeatureSelect,
    'featureunselected' : onFeatureUnselect
});
```

I skipping the code of "onFeatureSelect()" and "onFeatureUnselect()" ...

This is working very well.

Now i want to add additional new layers (OpenLayers.Marker as content) to show on the map (also working well) with the same functionality (showing popups...).

If I copy the code above and apply on the new layers the app is not working anymore...

Next try:

Adding the new Layer with setLayer() Method:

```
window.selectControl.setLayer(selectControl.layers.concat(newLayer));
```

But no success...

Thanks !

Comment: Julien's answer seems to be correct. Just one comment - if you are creating all your layers at once, you can skip setLayer and use window.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([markerLayer, newLayer]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the right thing, but concat() doesn't return you what you think.

The correct way of doing this is:

```
window.selectControl.setLayer([layer1,layer2]);
```

If you want to use the layers in your selectFeature variable, then make sure you use the right one. If you have only one layer, the `selectControl.layers` will be `null` and you have to use `selectControl.layer` instead. So your code should look like this (untested):

```
if(selectControl.layers) {
    window.selectControl.setLayer(selectControl.layers.concat(newLayer));
} else {
    window.selectControl.setLayer([selectControl.layer, newLayer]);
}
```